# Querying a JSON REST Service with POSTMAN/Rest Client

Tags: json, rest, restlet, postman

I have a simple RESTLET Service which returns a JSON representation, as shown below:

```
@Override
    @Post("json")
public Representation helloWorld() {
    Representation representation = new JacksonRepresentation<Hello>(new Hello("Hello World"));
    representation.setMediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    representation.
    return representation;
}
```

When I query this using cURL I get the response as expected:

```
{"greeting":"Hello World"}
```

However I do not get a response when I use the browser or POSTMAN or indeed any other web REST client. I get the response 'Could not get any response' from POSTMAN.

The preview of the POSTMAN request is:

```
POST /testingrestlet/hello HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:6000
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 5141cd87-505c-e813-0045-3b7f4aa54144
```

I would at least have expected a REST client such as POSTMAN to work, or am I missing something?

Any help appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With help from Thierry's comments the issue was traced down to Google Chrome blocking requests to port 6000 as it considers them unsafe. The error was only visible in Chrome Debug mode where the **ERR_UNSAFE_PORT** error was reported. Changing to a higher port resolved the issue! Detail of this error can also be found here: https://superuser.com/questions/188006/how-to-fix-err-unsafe-port-error-on-chrome-when-browsing-to-unsafe-ports

Answer (score 3):

I think that you should use an header `Accept` for the content negotiation (conneg). Your request should be:

```
POST /testingrestlet/hello HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:6000
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 5141cd87-505c-e813-0045-3b7f4aa54144
```

As a matter of fact, since you specify the extension "json" in the annotation, Restlet expects that this header was sent with one of possible media types for JSON content. This hint is used to select the method for processing... You shouldn't have this problem if you remove the extension, as described below:

```
@Post
public Representation helloWorld() {
    Representation representation
        = new JacksonRepresentation<Hello>(new Hello("Hello World"));
    representation.setMediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    (...)
    return representation;
}
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Hi Thierry, tried the additional Accept header and also just removed the json hint. Still no luck :(. Interestingly POSTMAN provides a CURL version of its query which works from the command line. (curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Postman-Token: 58bb4b2e-fa2d-e204-7a8b-e7e83766f1a1" -d '' http://127.0.0.1:6000/testingrestlet/hello)

Comment: Hello, is there an error in the returned payload or a message you can send me? Thanks!

Comment: I just made a real test with the code you provided and by adding no specific header and it works for me. I use chrome 41.0.2272.118 (linux) and postman 0.8.4.14.

Comment: POSTMAN returns: 'Could not get any resopnse. This seems to be like an error connecting to http://....'. The response status was 0. REST Console returns : 'Connection Failed!' Advanced Rest Client Returns: '0 no response'

Comment: One other detail which may be useful is that I am doing this on Android. The Restlet server is running on Android. (I have done the port forwarding etc as demonstrated by curl)

Comment: Ok. Could you make a try with a method `GET` (annotation `@Get` instead of `@Post`? Thanks!

Comment: It could be a CORS issue... Can you have a look at sent requests within Chrome debug? Especially if options requests are sent and their corresponding answers...

Comment: Tx Thierry I should be able to try your last 2 suggestions in next 2 hours and update you. Appreciate your time.

Comment: Hi Thierry, I have managed to solve the issue - your point about Chrome Debug was the trigger. Chrome Debug was showing an error of ERR_UNSAFE_PORT. The port is deemed unsafe and thus is blocked! Thanks for your help. I may well be back when I try to make an asynch REST call!